# Wordpress & CSS: A trouble of an image which is above the rounded box

Tags: image, wordpress, css

I have a trouble that I can't solve in a blog of WordPress. I don't know if it's bug or they are in confilcts. Firstly, see the image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdTuj.png

Notice the 3D rounded border and the white and black shadow in this image. This image is above the author avatar image's box. I can't correct it. See the example of JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZUben/

I use the Graphene theme for Wordpress the which is updated:
http://www.khairul-syahir.com/wordpress-dev/graphene-theme#.UXCgoivwLRY

Follow my styles:

```
.gutter-right {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

...

.post-avatar-wrap {
    float: right;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    background: #fff center;
        -moz-border-radius: 15px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 3px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.35), inset 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,1);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 3px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.35), inset 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,1);
        box-shadow: 1px 3px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.35), inset 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,1);
        margin-top: -10px;
}

...

.author-avatar-wrap {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    background: #fff center;
        -moz-border-radius: 15px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 3px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.35), inset 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,1);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 3px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.35), inset 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,1);
        box-shadow: 1px 3px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.35), inset 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,1);
        margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if I got it right, but you can apply all the styles to the image. Simply change line 5 in your JSFiddle to: `#author-avatar-wrap img`

Comment: @Sven, I tested it and it works, but it doesn't show the inset shadow.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here we go: set the image `relative` and also apply a `z-index` for this image which is lower than the `z-index` of the wrapper. Moreover we will have to apply the CSS3 border-styles to both, `div` and `img`.

So go and take a look at my fork of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ShwkP/

I've also created a separate class called `border-styles` in case we will have more elements with the same effect. Simply apply it to all elements to get this kind of border.

Remembar that this is CSS3 and will not work cross browsers, because neither [border-radius](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius) nor [box-shadow](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow) is fully supported!

Comment: 2hey if I replaced the symbol the point `.` for `#`, it won't work, because `.author-avatar-wrap` is original from the theme. It's from Wordpress. Wordpress uses PHP. But can I replace it or just add?

Comment: Yes, you can add `class="border-styles"` to every element to get exactly this effect. If you are not able to do this you can add the code like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wwCg9/

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't show the shadow, I replaced `.author-avatar-wrap`for `div#author-avatar-wrap`. At the Wordpress PHP files, as loop-single.php. See the little part:

Comment: `<div class="author-info clearfix">
 <div <?php graphene_grid( '< 'author-avatar-wrap', 2, 2, 2, true ); ?>>
 <?php
 if ( $author_imgurl = get_the_author_meta( <br/>'graphene_author_imgurl' ) ) { 
  echo '<img class="avatar" src="' . $author_imgurl . '" alt="" />'; 
 } else { 
  echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), graphene_grid_width( '', 2 ) ); <br/>
 } 
 ?> 
    </div> `

Comment: hmm, perhaps you can add the styles to the `author-info` upper class, but I'm not sure if this will do it for you. You can give it a try like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Hg9qJ/

Comment: Where in the theme will the author-avatars appear? Can I take a look at the website?